# reactjs error Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, babeljs

I am creating reactJS in .Net Core framework. I am using ReactJS as CDN in my .net app and My React App is throwing an error: require is not defined. I am attaching my code below:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var ReactBsTable = require('react-bootstrap-table');
var BootstrapTable = ReactBsTable.BootstrapTable;
var TableHeaderColumn = ReactBsTable.TableHeaderColumn;

var products = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Product1",
    price: 120
}, {
    id: 2,
    name: "Product2",
    price: 80
}];

ReactDOM.render(
    <BootstrapTable data={products} version='4'>
        <TableHeaderColumn isKey dataField='id'>Product ID</TableHeaderColumn>
        <TableHeaderColumn dataField='name'>Product Name</TableHeaderColumn>
        <TableHeaderColumn dataField='price'>Product Price</TableHeaderColumn>
    </BootstrapTable>, document.getElementById('content')
);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this,

Main html file where you are using cdn add this.

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel"></script>

<!-- Load our React component. -->
<script src="new_component.js"></script>

<!-- ... existing HTML ... -->

<div id="new_component_container"></div>

<!-- ... existing HTML ... -->
```

In the component file do this,

```
import ReactBsTable from  'react-bootstrap-table';
var BootstrapTable = ReactBsTable.BootstrapTable;
var TableHeaderColumn = ReactBsTable.TableHeaderColumn;

var products = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Product1",
    price: 120
}, {
    id: 2,
    name: "Product2",
    price: 80
}];

const domContainer = document.querySelector('#new_component_container');
ReactDOM.render(
  <BootstrapTable data={products} version='4'>
    <TableHeaderColumn isKey dataField='id'>Product ID</TableHeaderColumn>
    <TableHeaderColumn dataField='name'>Product Name</TableHeaderColumn>
    <TableHeaderColumn dataField='price'>Product Price</TableHeaderColumn>
  </BootstrapTable>, 
domContainer);
```

For react bootstrap table also , use `import` only if you are installing the library. Again if you are using cdn for that too then `import` won't work.

For more info related to react cdn please view this.

https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html

Comment: Thank You so much Puja, but unfortunately it's not working ... However I am trying to find another library... But Above all these... Thanks again for your help and cooperation.

Answer (score 0):

Try using ES6 `import` instead of `require`

ie., try

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import ReactBsTable from 'react-bootstrap-table';
```

Because `require` is not inbuilt react api. 
You need to install extra library for using `require` in react. CommonJs provides api for module loader like `require`

Comment: But it's not working that way also, I changed that before with *import* but still throwing same error

Comment: ohh.... it seems like you are using cdn for react. If you are using cdn then you don't need to import it. Just add babel cdn also so that jsx can be transpiled into js

Comment: Can You please check the upper code and rectify the main thing I am missing...?
I've added Babeljs.

Here is the cdn: <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>